# Getting a new FabricJS-Canvas at every rerendering in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

I have my following code, where I get a list of names by my props. 
For every element I am creating an fabric.IText.

The problem: my page is like a todo list. So when I add a todo, the FabricCanvas Component is rerendeing. Everytime when this happens, I get a new canvas IN my old canvas.

I tried to init the fabric.Canvas in componentDidMount and componentWillMount, but both versions are not working.

I am using tabs, so when I change my tab and then change back, I get a new canvas again.

-->

```
import React from 'react';
import fabric from 'fabric';

var canvas;

var FabricCanvas = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function(){
 return{
  elements: this.props.elements
 };
},

initiateWidgets: function(){
 canvas = new fabric.Canvas("FabCan");

for (var key in this.state.elements){
  var temp = new fabric.IText(this.state.elements[key]);
  canvas.add(temp);
},

render: function(){
 this.initiateWidgets();
  return(
    <canvas id="FabCan"> </canvas>
  );
 }
});

module.exports = FabricCanvas;
```

Comment: Looks like your render calls your initialize.  That might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    do something with newProps
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to stop from rendering the same thing again try to use [shouldComponentUpdate()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) mathod that rectJS provides it. I haven't use it so far, but [here's](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-component-lifecycle-updating) a good tutorial that could help you out. Using props with `getInitialState()` is a bad practice in react.